# Parse URL parameters with "&" characters without an "=" after

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, object

I've got the following code, so I can get parameters from a url.

However one of the parameters has a `&` sign in the text resulting in the text after it being cuts off. how do I get the & sign to display with the corresponding text after it?

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }

 var cmp = getUrlVars()["cmp"];
    document.getElementById("currentMemberPackage").value = cmp;
    var replaced = cmp.replace(/%20/g, " ");
```

Example URL = `?Club%20Plus%20Health%20&%20Fitness` (I can't change this as it has `&` in the data which is pushing through into the URL)

**Displays:** Club Plus Health

**Should be:** Club Plus Health & Fitness

Comment: But don't use regex to parse the URL. Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: @mplungjan Can you use HTML entity codes in URLs?

Comment: Why don't you use `encodeURIComponent` instead? It was built for that purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: That or %26 ....

Comment: @briosheje OP is not encoding that string on the client, he is decoding it

Comment: 1) This is a bug  on the data provider side, please let them know, 2) there is a way to extract the values 100% correctly if you know all possible key values, 3) there is a fragile generic non-100% work-around for this, like `/[?&]+([^=&]+)=(.*?)(?=&[^=&]+=|$)/gi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug on the data provider side, please let the data provider know as that should be  fixed.

There is a way to extract the values 100% correctly if you know all possible key values and they are not too many. In that case, the regex could look like

```
new RegExp("[?&]+([^=&]+)=(.*?)(?=&(?:" + your_keys.map(function(x) {return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');}).join("|") + ")=|$)", "gi")
```

There is a fragile generic non-100% work-around for this, like

```
/[?&]+([^=&]+)=(.*?)(?=&[^=&]+=|$)/gi
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VN01UX/1). You may use it until the data provider fixes the issue and you do not know all possible keys.

**Details**

- `[?&]+` - 1 or more `?` or `&` chars
- `([^=&]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `=` and `&`
- `=`  - an equal sign
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=&[^=&]+=|$)` - followed with `&`, one or more chars other than `=` and `&`  and then `=`, or the end of string.

Answer (score 2):

`&` in URIs is a special character - you'd have to URL encode it. Use `encodeURIComponent` to do this automatically:

```js
const str = "Club Plus Health & Fitness";
const encoded = encodeURIComponent(str);
console.log(encoded);
```

Comment: But he is not encoding them himself

Comment: @mplungjan But then it's a fault in the URI if it comes with a `&` included - the OP needs to fix the problem there, it'll be a broken URI otherwise and not easy to fix.

Answer (score 2):

1. The server MUST send `%26` instead of the invalid `&`. Whoever generated the URL needs to fix it server side.
2. Your function can then be replaced with the useful [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
var url = "?cmp=Club%20Plus%20Health%20%26%20Fitness"

var cmp = new URLSearchParams(url).get("cmp");
console.log(cmp)
```

Alternative if you cannot stop the invalid & from being sent.
Make sure to not blindly converting the & to %26 or you can break the code if there is more than one parameter :

```js
var url = "?someparm=a&cmp=Club%20Plus%20Health%20&%20Fitness"
           .replace(/&%20/g,"%26 "); // add the space!

var cmp = new URLSearchParams(url).get("cmp");
console.log(cmp)
```